# Problem exporting shp as CSV

Tags: qgis, shapefile, csv

I imported a shapefile into QGIS, made a copy of it, and edited that copy. My edits consisted in changes in the coordinates of a few points. I then exported this edited shapefile as a .csv. For peace of mind, I imported the .csv to check my edits but, to my surprise, there were no changes although I saved the edits.

If I export the edited shapefile as a .shp everything is fine but as a .csv it doesn't seem to recognize the edits. As anyone come across this problem?

Comment: I assume you clicked on "duplicate layer" in QGIS? Don't do this if you want to make changes on this duplicate. You need to physically duplicate your Shapefile on your device.

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand it now... I needed to recalculate the coordinates of the points I edited! I did this in the Attribute Table > Field Calculator > update exiting field > $X & $Y and it worked.

Thanks everyone who read this thread and special thanks to MrXsquared for replying.